# Should we add cut-and-paste Greek and special characters to the markdown help?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

This is related to the the following [recent post](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1027/what-kind-of-input-and-output-code-styles-are-acceptable-in-se).

Perhaps it would be helpful to provide a list of unicode Greek characters that people writing questions can cut and paste into their questions. I mean a list such as

Γ Δ Θ Λ Ξ Π Σ Υ Φ Ψ Ω α β γ δ ε ζ η θ ι κ λ μ ν ξ ο π ρ ς σ τ υ φ χ ψ ω

and, also, the following special characters

∈ ∉ ∃ ∀ ∞ °

I suppose these would be [added here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help). However, the way the question editor is now structured, I think it hard for people to find this page. First they have to notice the question-mark icon above the edit field and realize it is button that might be relevant. Then they must realize that they must click on *advanced help* to get to markdown FAQ. This is asking a lot of people new to *Mathematica*.SE.  Unfortunately, the new help pages don't seem to provide a link to the markdown FAQ, certainly not one I find obvious.

Comment: What I'd *really* like is a button in the editing toolbar that would replace all `\[Alpha]` characters with the Unicode equivalent, for a known-good set (meaning the ones that display properly and also copy back into *Mathematica* correctly).  I think I asked about this once (in a moderator chat room) but it didn't go anywhere.  Perhaps a Meta question would get more traction?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard now that (the replace functionality) would be really handy.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. Your magic button would be wonderful, but what are the chances of it being implemented?

Comment: @m_goldberg There's only one way to find out.  I hope that our site is important enough to StackExchange at this point to get some customizations if the community is behind them.

Comment: If you're using a *Mac*, there are apparently [some work-arounds](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/683/put-the-characters-somewhere-for-people-to-copy-paste)... But go ahead and propose the editing toolbar feature if you'd prefer that; can't make any promises, but including specific examples of *why* these would be useful would help.