# It's hard to find the markdown FAQ; can we make it easier?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed

In a [recent question](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1029/should-we-add-cut-and-paste-greek-and-special-characters-to-the-markdown-help) I wrote the following as an aside.

> However, the way the question editor is now structured, I think it hard for people to find this page. First they have to notice the question-mark icon above the edit field and realize it is button that might be relevant. Then they must realize that they must click on advanced help to get to markdown FAQ. This is asking a lot of people new to Mathematica.SE. Unfortunately, the new help pages don't seem to provide a link to the markdown FAQ, certainly not one I find obvious.

It turns out that it is also hard to find markdown FAQ by a direct search of the help facility. I made two searches today, one on "formatting" and the other on "markdown", and the results didn't include the markdown FAQ, as can be seen from the following screen captures.

[image: formatting-search-result.png]

[image: help-search-result.png]

If you go to the page [What topics can I ask about here?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), that page *does* have a link to the markdown FAQ, but it is buried deeply in the page and not all that easy to locate.

I strongly believe we would get better formatting from new users of the *Mathematica*.SE site if the markdown FAQ page were more accessible.

#### Edit

Given the recent change made in help center, as reported by rm -rf in his answer below, this complaint has be satisfied.

Comment: The official word is that this is a good idea and they'll try to move it to the help center. It might take a few days though, since they have some backlog to process before this.

Comment: Could you perhaps accept the answer below or upvote it? Not that I care, but the Community♦ bot will keep bumping this to the home page unnecessarily each month if there are no upvoted/accepted answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like this was implemented at some point during the week. The link to markdown formatting is now the first link in the help center under "The Stack Exchange Model".

[image]

Comment: Where is it? I don't have `The SE Model` paragraph there.